# My Swift code getting error Can't form range with upperbound < lowerbound

Tags: swift, algorithm

I try to run my code in leetcode [site](https://leetcode.com/problems/3sum/submissions/). In XCode this code compiled successful. But in leetcode is error:

> Fatal error: Can't form range with upperbound < lowerbound

Description of task:

> Given an array nums of n integers, are there elements a, b, c in nums
>   such that a + b + c = 0? Find all unique triplets in the array which
>   gives the sum of zero.

**My solution of this task is:**

```
class Solution {
    func threeSum(_ nums: [Int]) -> [[Int]] {
        var arr: [[Int]] = []

        var fIndex  = 0
        var sIndex  = 1
        var tIndex  = 2

        for i in fIndex..<nums.count-2 {
            for n in sIndex..<nums.count-1 {
                for z in tIndex..<nums.count {
                    let sum = nums[i] + nums[n] + nums[z]

                    if sum == 0 {
                        arr.append([nums[i], nums[n], nums[z]])
                    }
                }

                sIndex += 1
                tIndex += 1
            }

            fIndex += 1
        }

        return arr
    }
}
// delete this in leetcode site
let threeNums = [-1, 0, 1, 2, -1, -4]
let sol = Solution()
print(sol.threeSum(threeNums))
```

Where is the problem in my code?

Comment: *Hint:* Test your code with a single-element array ...

Comment: @Martin R yes, if i create array with single-element - I get this error in xcode too

Comment: Now think: What is `fIndex..<nums.count-2` in that case?

Comment: There are more problems with your approach. As an example, it finds only one triple in `[1, 2, 0, -1, -2]`

Comment: I'd suggest checking how to implement a permutation or combination algorithm (not sure what you need here as it's not specified if duplicate subsets are allowed), because that's basically a part what you need. Your current implementation is somewhere in between this.

Comment: @Sander Saelmans my algorithm is not correct...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all the other parts of your code works, you just need to check if the input array has less than 3 elements before the loops:

```
class Solution {
    func threeSum(_ nums: [Int]) -> [[Int]] {
        var arr: [[Int]] = []

        var fIndex  = 0
        var sIndex  = 1
        var tIndex  = 2

        if nums.count < 3 { return [] } // if there is less than 3 elements, there can't be any triplets

        for i in fIndex..<nums.count-2 {
            ...
```

Without the check, your code will fail when, say, `nums` has only one element, and `enums.count - 2` would be `-1`.